# perl uninitialized value in ... error

Tags: perl

I keep on getting initialization errors in this code on the use strict and can't figure out why. I set the scope right for all the variables - and the codes runs. Just don't understand the ugly errors.

```
2/15/2002   Joe   155
2/15/2002   Mike  108
2/15/2002   Pete  209
2/22/2002   Joe   158
2/22/2002   Mike  99
2/22/2002   Pete  163
3/1/2002    Joe   172
3/1/2002    Mike  125
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
our %dates;
foreach my $line (<>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($this_date, $this_name, $this_score) = split /\s+/, $line;
    my ($record_name, $record_score) = split /\|/, $dates{$this_date};
    if ($this_name && $this_score) {
            if ($this_score > $record_score) {
                    $dates{$this_date} = join "|", ($this_name, $this_score);
            }
    }
}

foreach my $date (keys %dates) {
    my ($name, $score ) = split /\|/, $dates{$date};
    print " The high_scored for $date was $name with $score\n";
```

```
shortcasper@shortcasper-laptop:~/perl$ ./hash_bowl bowl_linux
Use of uninitialized value in split at ./hash_bowl line 8,  line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $record_score in numeric gt (>) at ./hash_bowl line 10,    line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in split at ./hash_bowl line 8,  line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $record_score in numeric gt (>) at ./hash_bowl line 10,    line 7.
The high_scored for 3/1/2002 was Joe with 172
The high_scored for 2/15/2002 was Pete with 209
shortcasper@shortcasper-laptop:~/perl$
```

Comment: Where does `$dates` get its values from?

Comment: Something doesn't look right... `%dates` doesn't get values until `$this_score > $record_score` yet `$record_score` is the output from a split against values in `%dates`.

Comment: `%dates` records the highest score seen on previous lines.  Naturally, it doesn't have a value the first time a particular date is seen, and that `undef` is what causes the warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should `use warnings` instead of using `-w`.

The reason it complains is that the first time you encounter a particular day, `$dates{$this_date}` is `undef` (because it's never been set).  Splitting that gives you a warning and makes `$record_name` and `$record_score` `undef` (causing your second warning when you compare `$this_score` to `$record_score`).  The code works because numerically, `undef` is considered 0, but it generates warnings.

A simple fix is to use `$dates{$this_date} || '|0'` instead.  This provides a default value for new dates, setting `$record_name` to the empty string and `$record_score` to 0:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our %dates;
foreach my $line (<DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($this_date, $this_name, $this_score) = split /\s+/, $line;
    my ($record_name, $record_score) = split /\|/, $dates{$this_date} || '|0';
    if ($this_name && $this_score) {
            if ($this_score > $record_score) {
                    $dates{$this_date} = join "|", ($this_name, $this_score);
            }
    }
}

foreach my $date (keys %dates) {
    my ($name, $score ) = split /\|/, $dates{$date};
    print " The high_scored for $date was $name with $score\n";
}

__DATA__
2/15/2002   Joe   155
2/15/2002   Mike  108
2/15/2002   Pete  209
2/22/2002   Joe   158
2/22/2002   Mike  99
2/22/2002   Pete  163
3/1/2002    Joe   172
3/1/2002    Mike  125
```

But you should read the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and consider using a complex data structure instead of having to `join` and `split` your data just to store it in a hash.

Comment: This works - however I don't know why, to my neophyte understanding || '|0' looks like a 'or pipe in a 0'.  I tried setting the used values to '0' before the code execution (but that did not work). this gives me some food for thought. i'll figure this our eventually.

Comment: Your `split` expects to see `NAME|SCORE`, and it complains when it gets `undef` instead.  `$dates{$this_date} || '|0'` means "use `$dates{$this_date}`, or if that's false (meaning `undef`, because no string containing a `|` character is false) use the string `'|0'` (meaning blank name, 0 score).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your hash `%dates` is initialized but its values are not.  Your code tries to use the value of `$dates{$this_date}` before it is actually set (which happens a few lines later).

Comment: I tried setting $this_date to zero, but I still gets the same errors.   thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

%dates is a empty hash. So $dates{$this_date} is becoming "undef"

Change your inner condition like below to make it work; when there is no old records, it will insert in the dates hash.

```
 if ( !(defined  $record_score) || $this_score > $record_score) {
                $dates{$this_date} = join "|", ($this_name, $this_score);
        }
```

Comment: This looks like the most concise answer, but spits out an error.  
Global symbol "$record_store" requires explicit package name at ./hash_bowl line 10.
Execution of ./hash_bowl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: when i set the record store to our and give it a value of 0  -      Use of uninitialized value in split at ./hash_bowl line 11, <> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in split at ./hash_bowl line 11, <> line 7.